# Python: Merge two lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

Given two lists of dictionaries:

```
>>> lst1 = [{id: 1, x: "one"},{id: 2, x: "two"}]
>>> lst2 = [{id: 2, x: "two"}, {id: 3, x: "three"}]
>>> merge_lists_of_dicts(lst1, lst2) #merge two lists of dictionary items by the "id" key
[{id: 1, x: "one"}, {id: 2, x: "two"}, {id: 3, x: "three"}]
```

Any way to implement `merge_lists_of_dicts` what merges two lists of dictionary based on the dictionary items' keys?

Comment: what if lst2[0] = {id: 2, x: "five"} or if lst2[0] = {id: 2, y: "y"}

Comment: What if the "id" is the same, but the value is not?, Why not use tuples if your dictionaries are only 1 item? I think you are using dictionaries wrong?

Comment: are you using python 3?

Comment: @LostAvatar: how can you tell from the post? That's legal in both python2.x and in python3.x

Comment: @inspectorG4dget My possible answer would be different in python 3

Comment: @LostAvatar: Makes sense. I'd just post both solutions, but that's me

Comment: @LostAvatar if you're thinking of ChainMap you'd also want to check whether views are acceptable or if copies are required...

Comment: So, this is not a duplicate at all. The two are very significantly and importantly different.

Comment: @InbarRose this is not a duplicate.  It's merging a list of n dictionaries while the other is merging 2 dictionaries.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus , InbarRose: totally right on that. I voted for reopen.

Answer (score 22):

Perhaps the simplest option

```
result = {x['id']:x for x in lst1 + lst2}.values()
```

This keeps only unique `ids` in the list, not preserving the order though.

If the lists are really big, a more realistic solution would be to sort them by `id` and merge iteratively.

Comment: This will return a `dict_values` in python 3. which is a tad different from the desired result whihc is a plain list of dictionaries

Comment: @KimStacks you can convert it to a list by doing: `list(result)`

Answer (score 19):

```
lst1 = [{"id": 1, "x": "one"}, {"id": 2, "x": "two"}]
lst2 = [{"id": 2, "x": "two"}, {"id": 3, "x": "three"}]

result = []
lst1.extend(lst2)
for myDict in lst1:
    if myDict not in result:
        result.append(myDict)
print result
```

**Output**

```
[{'x': 'one', 'id': 1}, {'x': 'two', 'id': 2}, {'x': 'three', 'id': 3}]
```

Comment: this one should be declared as an answer, how come 6 years later the author of the question didn't vote for this?

Answer (score 13):

One possible way to define it:

```
lst1 + [x for x in lst2 if x not in lst1]
Out[24]: [{'id': 1, 'x': 'one'}, {'id': 2, 'x': 'two'}, {'id': 3, 'x': 'three'}]
```

Note that this will keep **both** `{'id': 2, 'x': 'three'}` and `{'id': 2, 'x': 'two'}` as you did not define what should happen in that case.

Also note that the seemingly-equivalent and more appealing

```
set(lst1 + lst2)
```

will NOT work since `dict`s are not hashable.

Comment: This is the most correct of all the answers as this will return a list as output in python3

Answer (score 3):

**BTW, you can use 'pandas' for such calculations:**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> lst1 = [{"id": 1, "x": "one"}, {"id": 2, "x": "two"}]
>>> lst2 = [{"id": 2, "x": "two"}, {"id": 3, "x": "three"}]
>>> 
>>> lst1_df = pd.DataFrame(lst1)
>>> lst2_df = pd.DataFrame(lst2)
>>> lst_concat_df = pd.concat([lst1_df, lst2_df])
>>> lst_grouped_res_df = lst_concat_df.groupby(["id", "x"]).agg(sum)
>>> print(lst_grouped_res_df.reset_index().to_dict('records'))
```

**Output:**

> [{'id': 1, 'x': 'one'}, {'id': 2, 'x': 'two'}, {'id': 3, 'x':
> 'three'}]