# Python Combine Dict

Tags: python

I have two dict. The elements in the dicts come in order.

```
[{'macaddress': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'}, {'macaddress': 'cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc'}]
```

```
[{'ipaddress': '192.168.1.1'}, {'ipaddress': '192.168.1.2'}]
```

I want to combine them as I show below;

```
[
 {
   'macaddress': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx', 
   'ipaddress': '192.168.1.1'
 }, 
 { 
   'macaddress': 'cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc', 
   'ipaddress': '192.168.1.2'
 }
]
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: [I downvoted your question because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Merge two lists of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561707/python-merge-two-lists-of-dictionaries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `l1` and `l2` the two lists, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a list comprehension with dictionary expansion:

```
l1 = [{'macaddress': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'}, {'macaddress': 'cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc'}]
l2 = [{'ipaddress': '192.168.1.1'}, {'ipaddress': '192.168.1.2'}]

out = [{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Output:

```
[{'macaddress': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx', 'ipaddress': '192.168.1.1'},
 {'macaddress': 'cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc', 'ipaddress': '192.168.1.2'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

For python 3.9+, you can use `|` operator between two dicts:

```py
macs = [{'macaddress': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'}, {'macaddress': 'cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc'}]
ips = [{'ipaddress': '192.168.1.1'}, {'ipaddress': '192.168.1.2'}]

output = [mac | ip for mac, ip in zip(macs, ips)]
print(output)
# [{'macaddress': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx', 'ipaddress': '192.168.1.1'}, {'macaddress': 'cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc', 'ipaddress': '192.168.1.2'}]
```

Answer (score -2):

##### Update

Please ignore this solution as it is incorrect.

##### Solution

Your question really is asking how to merge two different lists. You can simply merge them by doing:

```
a = [{'macaddress': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'}, {'macaddress': 'cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc'}]
b = [{'ipaddress': '192.168.1.1'}, {'ipaddress': '192.168.1.2'}]
c = a + b
```

However, there are many ways to merge lists. For more information, please check out [this](https://datagy.io/python-combine-lists/) list of eight different ways of merging lists.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but note OP wants to merge corresponding dictionaries in the two lists.  Your code appends the two lists.